# how to add column value in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am very new to java and i am developing an inventory management system(Its my first project ).I want to add the column values sententiously when a new row is created. please any one help me how to do so..
i want to sum the line total and show it as the arrow is located.[image].here is my code for table data.

```
int quantity, price;
Product p = new Product();
String[] result = new String[8];
String data[] = new String[7];
int i = 0;
result=p.getInfo(this.addItemField.getText());
for (String s : result) {
    data[i] = s;
    i += 1;
}
data[0] = "1";
quantity = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
price = Integer.parseInt(data[5]);
int tPrice = price*quantity;
data[6] = Integer.toString(tPrice);  //this is the field which i want to add for all row.
table.addRow(data);
this.addItemField.grabFocus();
addItemField.setText("");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`. When a TableModel event is generated you can loop through all the rows in the model and calculate a new total and then update your label.

Comment: While I doubt it would make much difference with a small number of rows and given the experience level of the OP this is certainly a suitable answer, I would prefer to use a slightly smarter solution in that you would monitor for add/remove/change events and update the total value based on those rows that have changed only.

Comment: Search the forum or the web for examples that use the TableModelListener.